# New and old WebJob versions both running following a deployment

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a continuous WebJob deployed via the Kudu API to `/api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}` as outlined [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#upload-a-continuous-job-as-zip). The App Service I'm deploying to has just a single instance running.

On occasion it's looking like the previous version of a WebJob is not removed following a deployment and it runs concurrently with the new version. This can continue to occur and I've seen up to nine processes running concurrently.

Application names redacted but they are identical for each process:

[image]

Stopping the WebJob via the Azure Portal causes the process under w3wp (scm) to stop but not the other "detached" processes.

The company I am working with has seen this with different WebJobs across different App Service Plans. We've also confirmed this outside of Azure with our own logs, where we see multiple versions of the same application running.

**Update 1**

I couldn't reproduce the issue using David's steps from the comments. I did however revert back to our old release process which stopped and started the App Service pre and post release. I've since realised this wasn't needed as WebJobs continue to run under scm even when the App Service is stopped.

However...

Post-deploy while the WebJob is at state "Starting":

[image]

Post-deploy while the WebJob is at state "Running":

[image]

I've created a dummy site named "dummy739047" on the same App Service Plan [as per the Kudu docs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) if a further investigation is needed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "also confirmed this outside of Azure with our own logs"? Do you mean by running Kudu locally outside of your Azure Web App?

Comment: Sure - I mean confirmed with our application logging external to Azure. We log messages along with the assembly version (stamped by TFS at build time). After deployment I see messages from both the new version and old (sometimes multiple).

Comment: That's definitely not normal. How often would you say you're seeing this? Can you repro by simply drag/dropping an updated exe (or even the same one, really) using Kudu Console into `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\YourJob`?

Comment: I couldn't repro by updating the exe (both same and new assembly versions) but I did repro via the Kudu API. I've updated the question with some additional info.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are seeing the issue in the case where it's 'starting' or 'running'? It really would be best to move conversation to a Kudu issue (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues). StackOverflow comments don't work well to go back and forth and discuss an issue. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay @DavidEbbo - I'd say the issue seems to start when the job is starting as that's when a process starts outside of the cmd.exe process? I'm not too sure though. I'll create a Kudu issue shortly.